# Apache Airflow date of the task's last successful run

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking for a way to establish when the last successful run of a certain **task** took place. I'm aware there's the context variable *prev_execution_date_success* but according to the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/macros-ref.html?highlight=prev_execution_date_success) this stores the information about the whole DAG not constituent tasks.

My DAG looks like this:
[image]
The DAG is designed to fail it at least one task fails. In a case of a failure the DAG is rerun. What I'm trying to achieve is to stop a task instance from executing heavy code if the task has been run successfully. For instance, while rerunning the DAG if the task *execute_query_heavy_code02* has been run successfully (on the same day) it shouldn't be run until the next day.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix (not the best practice, but good enough) without changing the DAG design is to have an Airflow `Variable` with the last successful execution date of `execute_query_heavy_code02`. First you get the variable value and compare with today, and if the date is older than today, execute the heavy code and set the variable value using [`set()` function](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/608dd0ddf65dac7f7eee2cb54628a93805b7ad66/airflow/models/variable.py#L152).

Code will look like this:

```py
# import section
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime

# inside the execute_query_heavy_code02 function
last_execution = Variable.get('heavy_task_last_execution_date')
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'  # change as you want
last_execution_dt = datetime.strptime(last_execution, date_format).date()
today = datetime.utcnow().date()

if last_execution_dt == today:
    # continue with next task
else:
    # execute heavy code
    Variable.set('heavy_task_last_execution_date', today.strftime(date_format))
```

If you want to change some part of the design you can use `BranchPythonOperator` (very well explained [here](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-branchpythonoperator/)).

Comment: I would go with this as well. But one thing to remember is to set a default value if the variable does not exists to not get errors/warning when you ll run the DAG first time. `last_execution = Variable.get('heavy_task_last_execution_date', default_var='whatever_here')`

Comment: Definitely @KarolosK.! You can also set that while you're creating the variable. Something like `1950-01-01` or just yesterday.